# How to remove private visibility in ActiveCollab 3.3.18

Tags: activecollab

I do not need the private visibility option anywhere.
I already installed a module to have another visibility option "Confidential" and now I don't want private visibility anymore.

[image: Check this for better understanding]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Normal and Private Visibility is added by activeCollab core. So, if you want to remove Private Visibility from dropdown, you need to make changes into core files. But, I don't recommend you to make changes in core files.

Hope that helps.

Thanks!

:Malay